# Upgrading Nginx on Raring Ringtail

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, nginx

I have have added ppa:nginx/stable to my apt sources. And have done an update. But when i try to upgrade, it fails to upgrade. Here are the list of commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Can you also put the output of these commands in the question?

Comment: @Cheiron 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    nginx is already the newest version.
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      dkms libgsoap2 ruby-archive-tar-minitar ruby-childprocess ruby-erubis ruby-ffi ruby-i18n ruby-json ruby-log4r ruby-net-scp
      ruby-net-ssh virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the install command what to install.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Thanks mitch. I am sorry for the typo but, i have done that ...

Comment: No @Mitch. I am sorry for the typo in the original question. In spite of doing "sudo apt-get install nginx" i am not able to update.

Comment: I tried the same on 13.04, and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It works on my vm... but somehow does not seem to work on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of this indicates ngix is already on the newest version. You can either try `sudo apt-get remove ngix` followed by `sudo apt-get install ngix` or try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (will look for updates for all of your packages) to make really sure.